# Como separar uma string de uma certa linha de um data.frame e ao mesmo tempo criar mais linhas?

Tags: r, dplyr

Tenho um data.frame com uma coluna com strings do tipo "123-235-203".

Por exemplo, a linha:

> string           coluna1 coluna2 
>   123-235-203      x        y

Quero separar essa string, de forma que a linha que  a contem se multiplique  preservando os valores das outras colunas:

```
strsplit(string, "-")
```

Transformando a linha em 3 linhas.

> string coluna1 coluna2 
>   123      x        y 
>   235      x        y 
>  
>   203      x        y

Há uma forma de fazer isso usando dplyr ou tidyr?

Comment: Você quer que a coluna da string vire três colunas?

Comment: @CarlosCinelli Desculpa, aí está. Eu quero separar a string, separar pelos traços e transformar em 3 linhas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O próprio Hadley nos oferece a resposta na vignette do tidyr.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
x = 1:3,
y = c("a", "d,e,f", "g,h"),
stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
df %>%
transform(y = strsplit(y, ",")) %>%
unnest(y)
```

Comment: de fato a sua solução é mais elegante :)

Answer (score 5):

Criar uma base para teste:

```
b <- data_frame(x = 1:10,y = 1:10, string = rep("123-235-203", 10))
```

Com o código a seguir você pode obter o que queria:

```
b %>% 
  separate(string, into = c('s1', 's2', 's3'), sep = '-') %>%
  gather(string, valor, -x, -y) %>%
  select(-string) %>%
  arrange(x)
```

- A função `separate` do `tidyr` transforma a sua string em três colunas (s1, s2 e s3).
- A função `gather` do `tidyr` multiplica as linhas.
- A função `select`do `dplyr` retira a nova coluna `string`que não é mais necessária.
- O `arrange` é só para ficar mais fácil de entender.

O resultados está abaixo:

```
# Source: local data frame [30 x 3]
# 
#    x y valor
# 1  1 1   123
# 2  1 1   235
# 3  1 1   203
# 4  2 2   123
# 5  2 2   235
# 6  2 2   203
# 7  3 3   123
# 8  3 3   235
# 9  3 3   203
# 10 4 4   123
# .. . .   ...
```

No caso em que as strings podem ter tamanhos variáveis, mas existe um máximmo de "-"'s você pode fazer assim:

```
b <- data_frame(x = 1:10,y = 1:10, string = rep(c("123-203", "123-203-555"), length.out = 10))

b %>% 
  separate(string, sep = '-', into = c("s1", "s2", "s3"), extra = "merge") %>%
  gather(string, valor, -x, -y, na.rm = T) %>%
  select(-string) %>%
  arrange(x)
```

- adicionei o argumento `extra = "merge"` no `separate` para que ele não retorne erro.
- adicionei o argummento `na.rm = T` para que ele não crie linhas com `NA`.

Comment: acho que isso não resolveria o problema, se as strigs são diferentes. Vamos supor que uma é "123-345"  e a outra é "123-12-345". A primeira rende 2 strings e a segunda, 3. De qualquer forma, achei uma forma no próprio tidyr. Vou postar a resposta embaixo. O Hadley é mesmo genial.

Comment: você tem razão, não tinha entendido que isso podia ser variável. Existe um máximo pelo menos?

Comment: acabei de postar uma resposta...

Answer (score 3):

Aqui é uma solução usando o pacote data.table

```
> library(data.table)
> dTbl <- data.table(x = 1:3, y = c("a", "d,e,f", "g,h"))
> dTbl[, .(y=unlist(strsplit(y, ','))), by=x]
   x y
1: 1 a
2: 2 d
3: 2 e
4: 2 f
5: 3 g
6: 3 h
>
```